# To find records where the number of digits after the decimal is greater than 3 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could you please help with the below requirement. I have a table in which a column has decimals values like

```
2.06976
1.089
1.04
1.104
1.1004
15.05791506
```

I want the query to filter out all records where the number of digits after the decimal is greater than 3. So the result would be

```
2.06976
1.1004
15.05791506
```

Appreciate if you can help me with it. I have been exporting data into excel and doing all sorts of stuff which is taking forever.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most efficient but is better than your current solution it seems.

```
declare @Decimals table
(
    Value decimal(11,9)
)

insert into @Decimals (Value) values (2.06976)
insert into @Decimals (Value) values (1.089)
insert into @Decimals (Value) values (1.04)
insert into @Decimals (Value) values (1.104)
insert into @Decimals (Value) values (1.1004)
insert into @Decimals (Value) values (15.05791506)

select 
    *
from
    @Decimals
where
    len(cast(CAST(Value - CAST(value as decimal(9,0)) as float) as varchar)) > 5
```

The where clause does the following:

1. Subtract the whole number from the decimal value leaving you with 0.xxxxxx.
2. Cast that to a float to remove trailing zeros
3. Cast that value to a string
4. Checks the length of the resulting string for a length over 5 because we know that the first two characters will always be '0.'.

Comment: I am already doing the same in excel Column(A) - Int(Column(A)) and then doing filters..the only problem is i am looking at a table with 135K rows

Comment: Did you not ask for a way to filter it out in SQL rather than doing it in Excel?